# what is the difference between ga:visitors & ga:visits in GA API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am playing with 
http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

While I found that there are `ga:visitors` & `ga:visits`.

What does the number mean for each?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ga:visitors` means *unique visitors* (i.e. "cookies" or unique browsers). `ga:visits` means visits. A visitor may make multiple visits in a date range. Also see this [Google Analytics help page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1257084?hl=en#visits_vs_visitors).

Comment: My `ga:visitors` is like 3000-4000 but why my `ga:visits` is only around 200? Does that mean every user read 200 pages per visit? I don't think I have that good content to attract them read 200 times...

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Are you sure your visitors number is higher than the visits? Normally, it's the other way round. If this happens on a page-level report, see [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en) or [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26710/how-can-of-unique-visitors-be-more-than-of-visits). Otherwise, I have no clue.

Comment: If ga:visitors (= ga:users) means unique visitors and ga:visits means visits, ga:visits must be always greater or equal to ga:visitors, so how it is possible that in my case, ga:visitors  is larger than ga:visits?